# Access Denied for ElasticBeanstalk DescribeConfigurationSettings API method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to run the DescribeConfigurationSettings API method for the ElasticBeanstalk as follow:

```
AWSElasticBeanstalk ebs = AWSElasticBeanstalkClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
        for(ApplicationDescription ad : ebs.describeApplications().getApplications()){
            System.out.println(ad);
            for(EnvironmentDescription ed : ebs.describeEnvironments(new DescribeEnvironmentsRequest().withApplicationName(ad.getApplicationName())).getEnvironments()) {
                System.out.println(ebs.describeConfigurationSettings(new DescribeConfigurationSettingsRequest().withApplicationName(ad.getApplicationName()).withEnvironmentName(ed.getEnvironmentName())).getConfigurationSettings());

            }


        }
```

However, I got the exception of Access Denied with the following message:

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.AWSElasticBeanstalkException:
> Access Denied: S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-eu-central-1,
> S3Key=eb_patching_resources/instance_patch_extension.linux (Service:
> Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID:
> NB44V0RXQG2WHH4T; Proxy: null) (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status
> Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:
> b058aa54-fc9c-4879-9502-5cb5818bc64a; Proxy: null)

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you get, it seems that you are missing some IAM permissions. I would start by adding [AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-servicerole.html#iam-servicerole-policy) Managed policy to your user.

This policy is probably more permissive than what you actually need, but it would be difficult to pinpoint exactly, which permissions are necessary.

Comment: thanks very much! this actually works but I think it is weird AWS stores the information in S3 bucket's object

Answer (score 1):

Amazon recommends using [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html).

**Updated Code**
Here is the Java V2 code for this use case.

```
 package com.aws.example;

   import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
   import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkClient;
   import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.*;
   import java.util.List;

    public class DescribeApplications {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        ElasticBeanstalkClient beanstalkClient = ElasticBeanstalkClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        DescribeApplicationsResponse applicationsResponse = beanstalkClient.describeApplications();
        List<ApplicationDescription> apps = applicationsResponse.applications();
        for (ApplicationDescription app: apps) {
            System.out.println("The application name is "+app.applicationName());
            DescribeEnvironmentsRequest desRequest =  DescribeEnvironmentsRequest.builder()
                            .applicationName(app.applicationName())
                            .build();


            DescribeEnvironmentsResponse res = beanstalkClient.describeEnvironments(desRequest) ;
            List<EnvironmentDescription> envDesc = res.environments();
            for (EnvironmentDescription desc: envDesc) {
                System.out.println("The Environment ARN is "+desc.environmentArn());
            }

        }
    }
  }
```

Output here:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the issue to access the DescribeConfigurationSettings? The screenshot does not execute the method in the question

Comment: describeEnvironments is now included in the code - which works perfectly with V2.